# 'computer says yes' error API ge.tt upload

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php 
$UploadURL = $CreatFile->upload->posturl;
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/picasa/preview_alpha.jpg';
$post = array(
    'filename'  =>  '@'.$file
);
$header = array(
    "Content-Length: ".filesize($file),
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $UploadURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$hasil = curl_exec($ch);
$hasil1 = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $hasil.$hasil1;
```

Result:

```
computer says yes
1
```

but in the share file, the file didn't upload
if use puturl then it can't conect to server
https://open.ge.tt/1/doc/rest#files/{sharename}/create

Comment: And this isn't working **HOW**?

Comment: It can't upload the file, i open the ge.tt account, go to the share, can't find the uploaded file.

Comment: __computer says NO__

Comment: You're not doing a file upload. you're doing a post with some strings. curl requires filenames/paths to be prepended with `@` to signify it's a filename. e.g. `$post=array('filename' => '@/path/to/file')`. or on newer php/curl versions, use [curlfile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Comment: @MarcB =>computer says yes -> the file not uploaded :(